# Error: Data source must be a dictionary (dplyr)

Tags: r, error-handling, dplyr

Im very new to R and did not find a solution for my problem. I really hope you can help me.

Although there are more columns and observations, my dataframe looks like the following:

```
dt <- data.frame(hid = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
                     syear = c(2000, 2001, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002),
                     employlvl = c("Full-time", "Part-time", "Part-time", "Unemployed", "Unemployed",
                                    "Full-time", "Full-time", "Full-time", "Unemployed", "Part-time", 
                                    "Full-time"),
                     relhead = c("Head", "Head", "Head", "Partner", "other", "Head", 
                                                  "Partner", "Head", "Partner", "Head", "Partner"))
```

---

```
| hid | syear |  employlvl  |       relhead         |
|-----|-------|-------------|-----------------------|
|  1  | 2000  |  Full-time  |         Head          |
|  2  | 2001  |  Part-time  |         Head          |
|  2  | 2003  |  Part-time  |         Head          |
|  2  | 2003  |  Unemployed |        Partner        |
|  2  | 2003  |  Unemployed |         other         |
|  4  | 2000  |  Full-time  |         Head          |
|  4  | 2000  |  Full-time  |        Partner        |
|  4  | 2001  |  Full-time  |         Head          |
|  4  | 2001  |  Unemployed |        Partner        |
|  4  | 2002  |  Part-time  |         Head          |
|  4  | 2002  |  Full-time  |        Partner        |
```

I would like to create another column which indicates the employmentlevel of the Partner and hope to get the following output:

```
| hid | syear |  employlvl  |         relhead       |      Partner      |
|-----|-------|-------------|-----------------------|-------------------|
|  1  | 2000  |  Part-time  |         Head          |        NA         |
|  2  | 2001  |  Part-time  |         Head          |        NA         |
|  2  | 2003  |  Part-time  |         Head          |    Unemployed     |
|  2  | 2003  |  Unemployed |       Partner         |        NA         |
|  2  | 2003  |  Unemployed |         other         |        NA         |
|  4  | 2000  |  Full-time  |         Head          |     Full-time     |
|  4  | 2000  |  Full-time  |        Partner        |        NA         |
|  4  | 2001  |  Full-time  |         Head          |    Unemployed     |
|  4  | 2001  |  Unemployed |        Partner        |        NA         |
|  4  | 2002  |  Part-time  |         Head          |     Full-time     |
|  4  | 2002  |  Full-time  |        Partner        |        NA         |
```

Currently I am using the following code. (Thanks again user ycw)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(hid, syear) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  filter(`relhead` != "Child") %>%
  spread(relhead, employlvl) %>%
  mutate(Relation = "Head") %>%
  rename(`Employment Partner` = Partner) %>%
  select(-Head)

dt3 <- dt %>%
  left_join(dt2, by = c("hid", "syear", "relhead" = "Relation"))
```

The code works absolutely fine for this small data set. But as soon as I try for my whole data I get the following:

```
Error: Data source must be a dictionary
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you run the code line by line, can you identify which line triggers the error? Since the error isn't replicable in the small dataset, we'll need more information on where it occurs.

Comment: There must be something different between the small example dataset and the actual dataset. Please examine the two datasets closely to see if there are any differences. You can also use the dput function to share all or just part of the actual dataset and post here for others to review.

Comment: Unfortunately I am working with sensitive data and I am not allowed to share them. But I think the problem is that I have more columns than in the dataframe above. If I add another column in the example dataframe I don't get the desired output. The error occurs with the last line of the code (select(-Head)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in other answers this is caused by non unique names. I was able to reproduce error by modifying your example (third element of `relhead`)

```
dt <- data.frame(
  hid = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  syear = c(2000, 2001, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002),
  employlvl = c("Full-time", "Part-time", "Part-time", "Unemployed", "Unemployed",
     "Full-time", "Full-time", "Full-time", "Unemployed", "Part-time", 
     "Full-time"),
  relhead = c("Head", "Head", "Employment Partner", "Partner", "other", "Head", 
     "Partner", "Head", "Partner", "Head", "Partner")
)
```

In that case `spread` creates first `"Employment Partner"` column and `rename` creates second. You should check if any of `"Employment Partner"`, `"Relation"` (and maybe `hid`, `syear`) is in `dt$relhead` (first one gives you error, second one is overwrite by `mutate(Relation=...)`).

Minimal reproducible example:

```
data_frame(g = c("a1","a2","a3"), i=1) %>%
    spread(g, i) %>%
    rename(a1 = a3) %>%
    select(-a1)
```

Answer (score 13):

Just came across the similar problem with same error message. After carefully checked my data set, I found that there are two columns having the same name. After I renamed one of them, then it works with no errors.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error message when I inattentively used 2 the same new names in `rename()` statement of `dplyr` package. Compare `names(df2)` with `unique(names(df2))` as you might have already had the same variable name before.

Answer (score 1):

If the error only occurs after you ran `select(-Head)`, you can probably find a workaround by using base R command to achieve the same thing.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(hid, syear) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  filter(`relhead` != "Child") %>%
  spread(relhead, employlvl) %>%
  mutate(Relation = "Head") %>%
  rename(`Employment Partner` = Partner)
```

The above part is the same as the original code. After that, run the following.

```
dt2$Head <- NULL
```

This is a base R command to remove the `Head` column, which is the same thing `select(-Head)` wants to do.

And then you can run the rest of the code to join the data frames.

```
dt3 <- dt %>%
  left_join(dt2, by = c("hid", "syear", "relhead" = "Relation"))
```

Since you did not provide a reproducible example, we could not figure out what this error message really means, but perhaps this workaround can help you achieve your task for now.

Answer (score 1):

It's being caused by doing the `select(-variable)` after the `rename` call.  I got the same error and when I removed the "rename" call and did the same select(-variable) it worked.

Have no clue why this is the case, but that's the trigger for the error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old now, but for all interested, the issue (I believe) is the difference in behavior between identically named functions in plyr, and dplyr. So when you have them both loaded, you can get unexpected results. I see this with group_by and summarize as well.

Generally, the best way I've found to deal with this is to just use dplyr::select, dplyr::rename, et cetera.

What'd be even better would just be to not use plyr because dplyr has it covered at this point, but I have some legacy code that uses plyr so I'm reticent to fuck around with it.